# About a theorem for integrability

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

Theorem:

> $f$ integrable on $[a,b] \iff \forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists P \text{ partition of } [a,b]: U(f,P)-L(f,P)< \epsilon$

Is this different from writing:

$f$ integrable on $[a,b] \iff \forall \epsilon >0$ $\exists P \text{ partition of } [a,b]: U(f,P)=L(f,P)$,

in the sense that we can make the difference as small as we want but $U$ is never equal to $L$?

This causes me a lot of confusion so I hope someone explains this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is different: equality is equality, and if you want to say "...in the sense that we can make the difference..." etc., then you write as in the first line.

Comment: @DonAntonio So the second line is wrong?

Comment: I'd say it is, or at least it is pretty misleading.

Comment: @DonAntonio Okay, many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. See DonAntonio's comment.
2. For a very concrete example, consider $f(x) = x$ on the interval $[a, b] = [0, 1]$. For any partition $P$ of $[0, 1]$, the upper sum of $f$ is *always* strictly larger than the lower sum of $f$, so your second version would say that $f(x) = x$ is not integrable.
3. You kinda know something is wrong in the second form, because there's a quantifier over $\epsilon$, but $\epsilon$ never appears after the quantifier.

Comment: any continuous non-constant function works as a counter.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to give a particular one so that the OP could experiment and verify -- I find students can often generalize, but it can be quite difficult for them to do the reverse. You say "any continuous non-constant function", and the student gets stuck thinking, "Which one should I choose? $x \mapsto x^2$? $x \mapsto \sin x$? $x \mapsto 13x + \pi$?" All work of course, but the verification is particularly simple for $x \mapsto x$.

Comment: This wasn't very obvious to me at first because if $x,y \in \Bbb R$ then $(\forall \epsilon > 0) |x-y|< \epsilon \iff x=y$. But now I think I understand the difference.

Comment: It doesn't say that there's a partition $P$ with the property that $U(f, P) - L(f, P) < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon$. (If it did, then you really WOUlD get equality. But the quantifiers are in a different order; given any $\epsilon$, you can find a $P$ that makes the statement true for that $\epsilon$, but which might well not work for, say, $\epsilon/2$.

Comment: Well, I haven't taken any mathematical logic classes yet so the logic part of calculus is what's confusing me most of the time. Any recommendations for a short read to cover the most important parts of mathematical logic?

Comment: Alas, no. Rosen's "Discrete Math" (I can't recall the exact name) book has an OK first chapter or so that covers quantifiers and a few other things. But as for books I'd recommend? Nah...I've got nothing. :(

Comment: @Michael: the result you quote deals with some fixed numbers $x, y$ independent of $\epsilon$. Here the numbers $U(f, P), L(f, P) $ depend on $\epsilon$. That's the crucial difference between two scenarios and one should be careful to understand the meaning of such statements. Issue is not so much about the use of logical quantifiers as many believe, it is about understanding the difference between variables and constants.